# Swift UIBezierPath starting offset from where it should

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

I have a Button that hides when pressed and instead an animation is shown that fills from left to right, indicating a wait time.

I have the following class which handles the animation:

```
//MARK: - Class: LinearProgressBarButtonView
class LinearProgressBarButtonView: UIView {
private var myWidth: CGFloat!
private var myHeight: CGFloat!

init(frame: CGRect, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    myWidth = width
    myHeight = height
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
}
    
private var lineLayer = CAShapeLayer()
private var progressLayer = CAShapeLayer()

func createLinePath() {
    // created linePath for lineLayer and progressLayer
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: myWidth, height: myHeight)
    let linePath = UIBezierPath()
    
    linePath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: rect.height/2))
    linePath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: myWidth, y: rect.height/2))
    
    // lineLayer path defined to circularPath
    lineLayer.path = linePath.cgPath
    // ui edits
    lineLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    lineLayer.lineCap = .square
    lineLayer.lineWidth = myHeight
    lineLayer.strokeEnd = 1.0
    lineLayer.strokeColor = colors.Blue.cgColor
    // added circleLayer to layer
    layer.addSublayer(lineLayer)
    
    // progressLayer path defined to circularPath
    progressLayer.path = linePath.cgPath
    // ui edits
    progressLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    progressLayer.lineCap = .square
    progressLayer.lineWidth = myHeight
    progressLayer.strokeEnd = 0
    progressLayer.strokeColor = colors.red.cgColor
    // added progressLayer to layer
    layer.addSublayer(progressLayer)
}

func progressAnimation(duration: TimeInterval) {
    // created circularProgressAnimation with keyPath
    let linearProgressAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
    // set the end time
    linearProgressAnimation.duration = duration
    linearProgressAnimation.toValue = 1.0
    linearProgressAnimation.fillMode = .forwards
    linearProgressAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = true
    progressLayer.add(linearProgressAnimation, forKey: "progressAnim")
}

func endAnimation(){
    progressLayer.removeAllAnimations()
}
}
```

I have set all necessary constraints, which are all correct. Using

`linearProgressBarButtonView = LinearProgressBarButtonView(frame: .zero, width: bookButton.frame.width, height: bookButton.frame.height) linearProgressBarButtonView.createLinePath()`

I can create the view and later add it as a subview.

I can now use `linearProgressBarButtonView.progressAnimation(duration: linearViewDuration)` to start the animation, which works exactly as it should. However, the animation does not seem to start at x = 0, but further along the way (somewhere at around 15%). Here is a screenshot of the first second of the animation, which is supposed to last 60 seconds:

[image: Screenshot]

I can't seem to figure out why. As far as I understand, it should start from x = 0. And the width should be the exact same width as the view has, which I pass when generating the animated view. Why is it starting with an offset then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *main* problem is:

```
lineLayer.lineCap = .square
// and
progressLayer.lineCap = .square
```

Those need to be `.butt`

When set to `.square` one-half the line-width will be "added" on each end. Here, the line path goes from `0,20` to `260,20`, with a `.lineWidth = 40`:

[image]

You can easily see what's going on by setting `layer.borderWidth = 1` on your view ... it will look similar to this:

[image]

So, that change should fix your issue.

However, I'd suggest -- instead of saving width/height and having to call `createLinePath()`, move that code into `layoutSubviews()`. That will always keep your line path correct, even if you change the frame at a later point:

```
class LinearProgressBarButtonView: UIView {
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() {
        layer.addSublayer(lineLayer)
        layer.addSublayer(progressLayer)
    }
    
    private var lineLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    private var progressLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        let linePath = UIBezierPath()
        
        linePath.move(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.midY))
        linePath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.midY))

        lineLayer.path = linePath.cgPath
        // ui edits
        lineLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        lineLayer.lineCap = .butt
        lineLayer.lineWidth = bounds.height
        lineLayer.strokeEnd = 1.0
        lineLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.systemBlue.cgColor

        progressLayer.path = linePath.cgPath
        // ui edits
        progressLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        progressLayer.lineCap = .butt
        progressLayer.lineWidth = bounds.height
        progressLayer.strokeEnd = 0.0
        progressLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.systemRed.cgColor
    }
    
    func progressAnimation(duration: TimeInterval) {
        
        // created ProgressAnimation with keyPath
        let linearProgressAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
        // set the end time
        linearProgressAnimation.duration = duration
        linearProgressAnimation.fromValue = 0.0
        linearProgressAnimation.toValue = 1.0
        linearProgressAnimation.fillMode = .forwards
        linearProgressAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = true
        progressLayer.add(linearProgressAnimation, forKey: "progressAnim")
        
    }
    
    func endAnimation(){
        progressLayer.removeAllAnimations()
    }
}
```

Comment: how come every time I see any good answer to any Swift-related question, your name always comes up? Thanks a lot, works like a charm and I learned something new :)